# List of all Windows administration command line tools

Tags: windows, command-line, administration

I sometimes have to use Windows command line tools like `netsh`, `route` or `ipconfig`.

Is there a place where all the Windows administration command line tools are listed?

Of course, there is MSDN for that, but it is for their documentation, I did not find a kind of page with the list of all these commands.

What would be also nice is the description of the GUI equivalent of these tools, or whether there is no GUI equivalent to these tools.

Comment: List [*all*](https://i.chzbgr.com/completestore/12/5/29/H3bIShqgk0-lH8Syjp5onw2.jpg) the tools? That might be difficult...

Comment: Only those bundled with Windows (NOT cygwin and so on). Aren't there any list of them? Even by category?

Comment: I don't know -- but the problem is, not every tool is included in Windows. A lot of "administration" tools have to be downloaded separately (e.g. ImageX), so the question is, how do you limit the scope of this...

Comment: does this help SS.64 - http://ss64.com/nt/

Comment: I limit the scope of it to those bundled with Windows (let's say, Windows 7). If some others are very interesting and provided by Microsoft, I am also interested. But no "third party" tools.

Comment: @mic84: yes it does!

Comment: :O no `BCDEdit` in that list!

Comment: I still feel like this would be useful as a reference. What would be a better stackexchange for this type of question? I would *really* like the same level of power I get on *nix on Windows, but I don't quite know where to start.

Comment: After all this years they published a PDF
 https://download.microsoft.com/download/5/8/9/58911986-D4AD-4695-BF63-F734CD4DF8F2/ws-commands.pdf

https://www.ghacks.net/2018/05/07/microsoft-publishes-windows-command-line-reference/

Answer (score 3):

[Microsoft has mostly eliminated Command Prompt information from the Help files distributed with Windows 7 and Vista](http://sourcedaddy.com/windows-7/getting-more-information.html), However, you can get the command-line reference list from the help documents of Windows Server family (or Windows XP).

Here's some online command-line reference lists from Microsoft [technet](http://technet.microsoft.com) sites.

- [Windows Server 2008 Command-line reference A-Z](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772390)

  Applies To: Windows 7, Windows Server 2003, Windows Server 2003 R2, Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Vista
- [Windows Server 2003 Command-line reference A-Z](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc778084.aspx)

  Applies To: Windows Server 2003, Windows Server 2003 R2, Windows Server 2003 with SP1, Windows Server 2003 with SP2
- [Windows XP Command-line reference A-Z](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490890.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a couple.  I'm assuming you want commands other than simple file management commands like `dir`, `attrib,` etc.  Others can add.  There's more commands often used on the server versions of Windows and the "Resource Kit Tools."  Note that PowerShell is much more comprehensive in this regard.

Furthermore, given the way the Windows component architecture works, it's possible to do strange things like call functions in .DLL's to do things.  A complete list of this is probably not possible unless you are terribly familiar with Windows internals.

`ipconfig` - display network interface IP address information

`nslookup` - perform DNS lookup

`nbtstat` - NetBIOS over TCP/IP utility

`sc` - commandl ine interface to control and configure services

`reg` - perform registry operations

`netsh` - perform configuration changes on network interfaces

`route` - display or change routing table  (There's also an `ipxroute` command which works if you have NWLink installed)

`schtasks` - command line interface to Task Scheduler.

`wevtutil` - command line interface to Event Viewer.

`getmac` - displays MAC addresses of all interfaces.

`devcon` - command line interface to Plug and Play subsystem - think of it as a command line Device Manager.

`fsutil` - filesystem-related operations

`chkdsk` - check filesystem on a volume

`ftp` - command line ftp client

`format` - format a volume

`label` - change volume label

`net` - performs a wide variety of "server" type operations including drve mapping, service control, user management, etc.

`powercfg` - configure power related settings.

`regsvr32` - register/unregister DLLs

Answer (score 0):

Run `ntcmds.chm` in command line.

Comment: 'ntcmds.chm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.